# Carver amp/receiver speaker problem

Tags: electronics, amplifier

I have a Carver amp/receiver withy phono, cd and tape inputs, two sets of speakers A and B.  From time to time the right speakers (or the left) will simply go out.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a corrosion problem with one of the knobs or switches on the amp.  You may also [hear a "scratchy" sound when you turn the volume](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/791/scratchy-volume-pot) or balance knobs.

I have an old Kenwood amp that I use for my studio monitors that has the same problem.  When I flip the switches and turn the knobs back and forth it usually fixes the problem and everything works fine...  ...for a while.

**The Solution**:

Try using [DeoxIT](http://www.guitarcenter.com/CAIG-DeoxIT-D5S-6-Spray--Contact-Cleaner---Rejuvenator--5-oz--101175859-i1134929.gc) on the knobs and switches on the amp.  It will clean up the corrosion and should fix the problem with the speakers cutting out.